# When emitting a date in a CouchDB Map function - what is being called on the date object?

Tags: javascript, date, dictionary, key, couchdb

I'm experimenting with emitting Date objects as the key in a map function, and can't understand what is happening when the Date object isn't parsed correctly.

Using a simple example record set :

```
{
   "_id": "e3681a4f5ce5685b777659804e9fd9f1",
   "date": "2016-04-04T16:02:09.058+01:00" // okay datestring
}

{
   "_id": "99a5c50967a279e1d7fef1a4ed18d7fb",
   "date": "2016-04-34T16:02:09.058+01:00" // invalid datestring
}

{
   "_id": "43a435ce71a4b92ab0dd4fe9d91fbbb2",
   "date": "text" // invalid datestring
}
```

And the following map function :

```
function(doc) {
  var date = new Date(doc.date); 
  emit(date,1);  
}
```

Gives the following result set :

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"43a435ce71a4b92ab0dd4fe9d91fbbb2","key":null,"value":1},
{"id":"99a5c50967a279e1d7fef1a4ed18d7fb","key":null,"value":1},
{"id":"e3681a4f5ce5685b777659804e9fd9f1","key":"2016-04-04T15:02:09.058Z","value":1}
]}
```

Where are the null values for the key coming from? It's not calling `toString()` or `toISOString()` on the dates as they would return `"Invalid Date"`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, it works like this:

```
function emit(key, value) {
    var row = { id: currentDocId(), key: key, value: value };
    appendToOutput(JSON.stringify(row));
}
```

So it should be easy to see where the values come from, given that `toJSON()` on an invalid date returns `null`.

In reality it's not the `emit()` function that does this at all, but the default rendering implementation used when no [list function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#listfun) is supplied.

```
while (row = getRow()) {
    send(JSON.stringify(row))
}
```

Comment: Ah I think I see here.JSON.stringify() will parse the invalid date object to null, as outlined here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Ric Yes, `new Date("2016-04-34T16:02:09.058+01:00").toJSON()` returns `null`.

Comment: I just realised, that when coding views with JavaScript in CouchDB, `Date.parse()` function returns `NaN` with date time strings like "2016-04-34 16:02:09". It has to be in format like "2016-04-34T16:02:09".